# Ocultar Archivo en Android - firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy descargando un **pdf** desde *Firebase* que está almacenado en `Storage` pero quiero que este oculto para el usuario.

El archivo se guarda en la carpeta `Android/Data/` pero esta visible cuando me meto en ella, puedo copiarlo y cortarlo si quiero.

Quisiera saber como ponerlo en **MODE_PRIVATE**, para que solo sea posible acceder desde la APP.

Pongo mi ejemplo de código:

```
StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
    final File rootPath = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "books");//aqui creo un directorio
    if(!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    }
    final File localFile = new File(rootPath,"libro"+ name +".pdf");//aquí creo el archivo que quiero ocultar
    if (localFile.exists()){
        libropdf.fromFile(localFile)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .spacing(10)
                .load();
    } else {
        ref.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                libropdf.fromFile(localFile)
                        .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                        .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(getApplicationContext()))
                        .spacing(10)
                        .load();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Utiliza getFilesDir para obtener la direccion interna de los datos de la app de esta manera no estara visible y se eliminara al desinstalar la app; Ejemplo en kotlin
`val storageDir: File = context!!.filesDir`

Puedes revisar el metodo saveImageToInternalStorage ahi se utiliza lo que te mencione [ejemplo](https://github.com/DjangoLC/Download_Images/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/django/com/downloadimages/AsynckTask.java)

Comment: Me sirvio, muchas gracias!